# SET NOCOUNT ON ИСпользование

Tags: sql-server

Объясните пожалуйста, как правильно использовать SET NOCOUNT ON/OFF В хранимах процедурах? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала разберемся, что это вообще за зверь такой, SET NOCOUNT.
Согласно [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189837(v%3Dsql.120).aspx), данная конструкция

> Запрещает вывод количества строк, на которые влияет инструкция Transact-SQL или хранимая процедура, в составе результирующего набора.

Такая информация очень даже может пригодиться при отладке, но потом, скорее всего, будет не нужна. 
Прописав SET NOCOUNT ON вы отключите вывод количества строк, тем самым увеличите производительность за счет сокращения объема трафика, особенно если у вас в процедуре есть циклы или процедура содержит несколько выражений сразу, но не возвращает большого количества строк.

Для подсчета строк, если вам это необходимо, лучше использовать [@@rowcount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187316%28v=sql.120%29). Одна из причин: если вы используете где-то в проекте DataAdapter или Command, то NOCOUNT может все [поломать](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters).

Стоит заметить, что если у вас на сервере NOCOUNT по умолчанию имеет одно значение, а в процедуре вы пишите другое, то локальное значение приоритетнее.
Значение по умолчанию можно установить в Management Studio (Сервис-Параметры-Выполнение запроса-SQL Server-Дополнительно):[image]

Ну и на англоязычном [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483732/set-nocount-on-usage) есть много интересных вопросов и ответов, касающихся NOCOUNT и его поведения, советую ознакомиться.

Comment: Маленькое замечание - на сервере не устанавливается "NOCOUNT по умолчанию", на скрине настройка SSMS, то есть клиентского приложения -  не сервера. Вообще это настройки текущей сессии.

Comment: @avocado03, если SET NOCOUNT имеет локальный контекст, зачем все пишут в конце хранимой процедуры SET NOCOUNT OFF? Как я понимаю, эта строка не влияет на настройки сервера по умолчанию.